# local stun server inside a closed LTE network

Tags: webrtc, stun, lte, peer

First of all, apologies if the title doesn't match the description.

We, in our organization are working on peer-peer video communication solution within a closedLTE network. For this purpose, we are using open source webrtc client peerjs along with their local peerjs server. The server by default refers to google stun server.

```
1. Is stun server required in case of closed LTE network?
2. If yes, can we make use of a open source stun server which could run locally instead of the default one?
3. If no, what are the changes I would need to do?
```

I have setup one open source stun server [https://github.com/enobufs/stun] but failed to carry out further connections with the clients.

I setup the server as per the instructions provided in the link. Now instead of the default stun server , I put the 'local-ip-address:port' and tried to make a connection between the peers. But it dint work.

```
var configuration = { "iceServers": [{ "urls": "local-ip-address:port" }] };
pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
```

Am i doing it the wrong way?
Please guide me through.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Coturn](https://github.com/coturn/coturn) is very popular stun/turn server with active community support.
Pre-built packages available at https://github.com/coturn/coturn/wiki/Downloads

You can test the server with [sample demo](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/)

If both the parties are in same network, then no need to configure turn stuff like credentials. [Read more](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/#after-signaling-using-ice-to-cope-with-nats-and-firewalls)

```
Configuring the peerConnection:

STUN server: //server_ip is coturn instance ip should be reachable from clients 
var iceServers= [{"url": "stun:server_ip:port"}];

or TURN server:
var iceServers= [{"url":["turn:server_ip:port"],"username":"turn_username","credential":"turn_password"}];
var pc_config = {"iceServers": iceServers};
var pc_constraints = {
        "optional": [{"DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement": true}]
    };
pc = new RTCPeerConnection(pc_config, pc_constraints);
```